# How do I get MS LightSwitch to recognize my View?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-lightswitch

I've created a View from a table in another database. I have dbo rights to the databases so viewing and updating is not a problem. This particular View did not have an "id" column. So I added one to the View by using ROW_NUMBER. Now I had a problem with a table, in the same database, not showing up in LightSwitch but that was solved by changing the id column to be NOT NULL. I haven't done any real manipulation in LightSwitch. I'm still in the Import Your Data Source stage (ie. very beginning).

This View, in LightSwitch, is going to be read-only. No updating or deleting. From what I've read, LightSwitch needs a way to determine the PK of a Table or View. It either reads it from the schema (column set as a PK) or finds a column set as NOT NULL and uses that as the PK. Well I can't seem to do either of those things in SQL Server or LightSwitch, so I am stuck as to how to get LightSwitch to "see" my View.

Comment: You could do with reading [Writing the perfect question](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx).

Comment: Well, [after seeing this link on fixing the problem](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/64534e95-ae07-4b8d-9064-f4deadae6438), I'll wait to see if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

for lightswitch to see your view you must have a primary key on a column of the table your are selecting from.
Example:

```
create table tbl_test
(
id int identity primary key not null,
value varchar(50)
)

create view vw_test
as
select *
from tbl_test
```

note:sometimes when you edit the primary key column in the view select statement it may cause lightswitch to not see it

Example:

```
create view vw_test
 select cast(id as varchar(50) id,...
```

lightswitch would not see the table

Hope this was helpful! :)

Comment: Dumb Tool still adds definition as "The key has been inferred and the definition was created as a read-only table/view".  REALLY ANNOYING - hasn't Microsoft heard of INSTEAD OF Triggers to handle updates through a View - it is 2013, not the dark ages!

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is create a view with an ID column equal to the row number.  Ensure the column you're basing the ID on is not null using the isnull() or coalesce() functions.

Example:

```
create view as
select distinct ID = row_number() over (order by isnull(Name,'')), 
Name = isnull(Name,'')
from My_Table
```