# Lightswitch Datasource views missing from list

Tags: sql, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2013

I just started using Lightswitch 2013 and I have created a new view in my SQL Server 2012 database but cannot see it in Lightswitch when I go to refresh the datasource.  Do I have to refresh some sort of cache or something?

```
ALTER VIEW viw_Months 
AS 
     SELECT DISTINCT MonthKey, MonthName FROM dbo.dim_Time
```

The Dim.Time table has a primary key on the DateID field.

Comment: Does the connecting user have rights to the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem was your view doesn't have candidate column to be primary key :

> LightSwitch must be able to infer a primary key for the view so that one row can be distringuished from another. If all of the view's columns are nullable then a primary key cannot be inferred and LightSwitch will not let you select it to be imported.
>
> [[social.msdn.microsoft.com : update datasource -> a particular view does not show up in list to add it to project](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19caa71d-088e-4984-8bf9-782ce72a4e52/update-datasource-a-particular-view-does-not-show-up-in-list-to-add-it-to-project?forum=lightswitch)]

Related SO Question : [How do I get MS LightSwitch to recognize my View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9895613/how-do-i-get-ms-lightswitch-to-recognize-my-view)

Comment: THANKYOU! Thats a bit tricky, should tell you after you click Update.